# Android - Error when uploading a bitmap to server C#

Tags: java, c#, android, .net, upload

When i make upload of a image in Android to the server (C #) it generates an error converting the image to byte Array, this happens with some images which is very strange because this error is not always generated, that is, depending the image is correctly converted or not.

The conversion code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmapPhoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);
final byte[] img_byte = stream.toByteArray();
final String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(img_byte, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

When receiving in C# I make the following conversion in the string, generating a byte Array and then for the MemoryStream.

```
byte[] novaFoto = Convert.FromBase64String(NovaFoto.FotoString);    
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(novaFoto))
{
    Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

depending at the image the error appears in either Convert.FromBase64String or Image.FromStream.

Can anyone help me with this? If you have another method i like this.Thanks!!

Comment: `it generates an error converting the image to byte Array, ` That conversion is done in your Android app. Which error? Please show the relevant lines from the Android logcat.

Comment: It is not on Android is on the server when converting the string to byte

Comment: `it generates an error converting the image to byte Array,`